# Is Windows Phone dead?

Tags: mobile-phone, windows-phone

I noticed that Amazon had a deal on the Nokia 6 for Prime Day that runs Android, not Windows Phone. I went to Nokia's web site and the tech specs basically indicate that it's fully subscribed to Google's services.

I was never a fan of Nokia, and even less so of Windows Mobile. I'm guessing it didn't work out since Nokia was their only hope for saving their mobile platform.

I'm also guessing they've sold off Nokia, since Microsoft would pack up and go into the pinball machine business rather than see Google Play running on their hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows phone is dead](http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/windows-phone-just-died-1281562), and [Microsoft has sold  the brand back to HMD (former Nokia Employees)](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/may/18/nokia-returns-phone-market-microsoft-sells-brand-hmd-foxconn).   - Thus Nokia will again sort-of be Nokia, and they will no doubt have Android phones.

Comment: Not sure what the downvotes were for. You answered my question and linked a couple sources. What's to complain about?

Comment: @WesSayeed I would expect that the downvotes were for answering a question that was blatantly off-topic here. We do have a [windowsphone.se] site but I suspect that this will be too fuzzy for migration.

Comment: @Mokubai; Thanks. I didn't even see there was a Windows Phone SE. There are so many...